# IIS 7 Classic Asp application Regional and Locale Cached?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, regional-settings

I have one Classic Asp application running in IIS 7. As I wanted to have UK regional settings, I have made changes in:

1. Control Pane's Regional settings
2. Manual changes to registry for HKEY_CURRENT_USER and all users under HKEY_USERS
3. IIS 7, Features, .Net Globalization settings

But I am still not getting the date time format I have set up which is "dd/MM/yyyy". This is obvious when I call CStr or FormatDateTime function in my application.

I have ever heard of IIS's locale caching. Does it have to do anything with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got localization set in your ASP page? It could be that your browser is using that to determine what date format should be shown.

We tend to get dates in the database in the normal format and then convert using FormatDateTime to get around it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But I do not separately set localization in my pages. Yet, it is not convenient for me to format and convert date time to use it. The fact that it is working on other machines makes me crazy. So, I am wondering if I have omitted or forgotten to do any steps to set locale correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the Language settings for Internet Explorer are set to English (US).